# Regex collection groups in C# when using an OR

Tags: c#, regex

If I have the following code:

```
Regex xp = new Regex(@"(\*\*)(.+?)\*\*|(\*)([^\*]+)\*");

string text = @"*hello* **world**";

MatchCollection r_Matches = xp.Matches(text);

foreach (Match m in r_Matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].ToString());
}

// Outputs:
// ''
// '*'
// '**'
// ''
```

How can I run the above regular expression and have the result of the first collection from either side of the OR appear in the same place? (ie. .Groups[1] returns either `**` or `_`, I gather this isn't how Regexes in C# work but is this achievable? and if so how?)

Comment: Have you tried naming the groups instead? `(?<name>...rest of group...)` and then `m.Groups["name"].Value`? Does that work?

Comment: I feel like having multiple groups of the same name could be problematic/not possible...

Comment: I assumed it wouldn't be, but it is! If you put that as an answer then I will accept it :)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Possible, and not problematic (hidden a bit though, you need to go into the `CaptureCollection`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the commenters said, you can use named groups for this.  .NET is more flexible than most of the other regex flavors in that it allows you to use the same name in different parts of the regex, with no restrictions.  With this regex:

```
@"(?<delim>\*\*)(?<content>.+?)\*\*|(?<delim>\*)(?<content>[^*]+)\*"
```

...you can extract the parts that interest you like this:

```
foreach (Match m in r_Matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Delimiter: {0}\nContent: {1}",
                      m.Groups["delim"].Value,
                      m.Groups["content"].Value);
}
```

And that's all there is to it.  Contrary to one of the other comments, you don't have to muck about with GroupCollections or CaptureCollections, or whatever.

Be aware that this particular problem can be solved easily in almost any flavor.  It's just that .NET is more flexible than most.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [backreference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx):

```
Regex xp = new Regex(@"(\*{1,2})(.+?)\1");

string text = @"*hello* **world**";

MatchCollection r_Matches = xp.Matches(text);

foreach (Match m in r_Matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].ToString());
}
```

This will match `**` or `*` followed one or more of any characters until it finds exactly what it had matched before (`**` or `*`).